# How to Get File Size of Files on FTP Server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I need a list of all the files (and associated file sizes) on an FTP server. I can get a list of files using CodeIgniter’s FTP class, but no idea how to get the file size. How do I get the file sizes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about CodeIgniter's FTP class, but what about this?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php

I assume that the FTP class' list_files() method doesn't provide this info.  Is that correct?

Comment: I think he wants to stick with CI's FTP functions (`ftp_rawlist()` would probably require at FTP connection opened using PHP's built-in functions). However, it looks like CI in fact doesn't offer the functionality.

Comment: @Pekka: The CI FTP class is a simple wrapper class for the standard PHP FTP functions, so it's easy to extend it and add an extra wrapper function that executes ftp_rawlist. CI's list_files just calls ftp_nlist btw.

Comment: ftp_rawlist did it for me. Just had to parse for the parts I was interested in.

Didn't want to use ftp_size as it's not always supported by servers.

Answer (score 2):

Just had a quick look at CodeIgniters FTP class.. As its written with backwards compat for PHP4 you could probabaly do this (hack job) if you must.

```
<?php
$files = $this->ftp->list_files('/folder/');

foreach ($files as $file)
{
  echo 'File:'. $file .' Size: '. ftp_size($this->ftp->conn_id, $file) .' <br />';
}
$this->ftp->close();
```

I wouldn't recommend this - It's probabably worth extending the main CI ftp class

```
class FTP extends CI_FTP
{

  function FTP()
  {
    // call parent constructor
    parent::CI_FTP();
  }

  // Single file size
  function file_size($file)
  {
    return ftp_size($this->conn_id, $file);
  }
}
```

Put the above into your application/libraries and save it as ftp.php. If you're running an updated version of CI it'll load your extension.

Answer (score 0):

Its relatively simple to extend the CI FTP class:

```
class MY_FTP extends CI_FTP {

    function MY_FTP()
    {
        parent::CI_FTP();
    }

    function get_file_size()
    {

    }
}
```

Essentially just make get_ftp_size() a wrapper for:

```
return ftp_size($conn, $file);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-size.php

I hope this helps (if you are stuck just skim through the ftp.php file of your install; you should soon find your way)

**Edit**

As wimvds rightly suggest's ftp_rawlist() might be the more preferable/easier option, i may even go so far as to suggest altering list_files() to use ftp_rawlist().

Comment: It will probably be easier to add a wrapper for [ftp_rawlist](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php), so you can have both the filenames and the sizes in one FTP command... You will have to parse the result though (since it just returns one string per file).

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is a chanche that the FTP server has ceratin functions disabled, or it won't let you call then(for example the filesize() function). 
Also, the standard filesize() http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php functionshould work over ftp

Answer (score 0):

Since CI is still PHP 4 compatible you probably can do it quick and dirty as follows :

```
$this->load->library('ftp');

$config['hostname'] = 'ftp.example.com';
$config['username'] = 'your-username';
$config['password'] = 'your-password';
$config['debug'] = TRUE;

$this->ftp->connect($config);
$files = ftp_rawlist($this->ftp->conn_id, $path);
```

In $files you should get one line per file, containing file permissions, owner/group, filesize and filename. You will have to parse this to display them separately.

DISCLAIMER : Just copy/pasted the connection info from the CI manual, added the last line based on the CI source code, YMMV :p.

Answer (score 0):

After hard work, this code works great!!!! and I want to share with the community (by MundialSYS)

```
function dirFTPSize($ftpStream, $dir) {
    $size = 0;
    $files = ftp_nlist($ftpStream, $dir);

    foreach ($files as $remoteFile) {
        if(preg_match('/.*\/\.\.$/', $remoteFile) || preg_match('/.*\/\.$/', $remoteFile)){
            continue;
        }
        $sizeTemp = ftp_size($ftpStream, $remoteFile);
        if ($sizeTemp > 0) {
            $size += $sizeTemp;
        }elseif($sizeTemp == -1){//directorio
            $size += dirFTPSize($ftpStream, $remoteFile);
        }
    }

    return $size;
}

$hostname = '127.0.0.1'; // or 'ftp.domain.com'
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$startdir = '/public_html'; // absolute path
$files = array();
$ftpStream = ftp_connect($hostname);
$login = ftp_login($ftpStream, $username, $password);
if (!$ftpStream) {
    echo 'Wrong server!';
    exit;
} else if (!$login) {
    echo 'Wrong username/password!';
    exit;
} else {
    $size = dirFTPSize($ftpStream, $startdir);
}

echo number_format(($size / 1024 / 1024), 2, '.', '') . ' MB';

ftp_close($ftpStream);
```

Good code!
Fernando

Answer (score -1):

Using the [file helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html)

```
get_file_info('path/to/file', $file_information)
```

> Given a file and path, returns the name, path, size, date modified. Second parameter allows you to explicitly declare what information you want returned; options are: name, server_path, size, date, readable, writable, executable, fileperms. Returns FALSE if the file cannot be found.

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to work through an FTP connection?