# how to get file size on ftp server using php?

Tags: php, ftp

i need a list of all the files on an FTP server. I can get a list of files using php , but no idea how to get the file size. How do I get the file sizes? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get File Size of Files on FTP Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211290/how-to-get-file-size-of-files-on-ftp-server)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
ftp_size
```

As in

```
int ftp_size ( resource $ftp_stream , string $remote_file )
```

To get the size of files over FTP.

For example:

```
$file = 'somefile.txt';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// get the size of $file
$res = ftp_size($conn_id, $file);

if ($res != -1) {
    echo "size of $file is $res bytes";
} else {
    echo "couldn't get the size";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

However only some FTP servers support this.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-size.php

Comment: if some file i check size, same syntax?

Comment: I have edited my answer with the example from the source link, this details how you would go about using this in a real example.